When does a bounded linear operator has no eigenvalue?
Suppose $T$ is  a bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space  $H$,
when does it has no eigenvalue?
I've heard that it's when range(T) is not closed. Is it true?
how to prove it?

No, it’s not true. Neither direction is true, actually. Multiplication along the diagonal by $1/n$ on $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ has plenty of eigenvalues, but its range is not closed. On the other hand, multiplication by $z$ on $L^2(\mathbb{T})$ has no eigenvalue, but its range is the entire space, in particular closed.

The two conditions are simply not related to each other at all. There are examples for all four different combinations (having eigenvalues, not closed range; having eigenvalues, closed range; no eigenvalues, not closed range; no eigenvalues, closed range).

As far as I can tell, there really aren’t any criteria for when $T$ has no eigenvalues. There are conditions that ensure $T$ has eigenvalues - like $T$ being compact and normal. But none of those conditions is necessary.
